# query the relationship and get result according to relation query

Tags: php, laravel

I want to do a query to get relations of a model and sort the parent model by the query which was done in my relation so like below :

```
 $data = Accommodation::with([  'accommodationRoomsLimited.discount', 'accommodationRoomsLimited', 'accommodationRoomsLimited.roomPricingHistorySearch' => function ($query) use ($from_date, $to_date) {
            $query->whereDate('from_date', '<=', $from_date);
            $query->whereDate('to_date', '>=', $to_date);
        }])->when($bed_count, function ($q, $bed_count) {
            $q->with([
                'accommodationRoomsLimited' => function ($q) use ($bed_count) {
                    $q->where('bed_count', $bed_count);
                }
            ]);
```

so when user send bed_count 3 for i this query only shows rooms that have bed_count of 3 and if they don't it shows the accommodation but with empty rooms object as relation . i want my result this way that if the room doesn't have the bed_count of 3 the accommodation it self wont show in result . how can i achieve that ?? thanks .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you use `whereHas` instead of `with`, you can do it:

```php
$data = Accommodation::with([  'accommodationRoomsLimited.discount', 'accommodationRoomsLimited', 'accommodationRoomsLimited.roomPricingHistorySearch' => function ($query) use ($from_date, $to_date) {
        $query->whereDate('from_date', '<=', $from_date);
        $query->whereDate('to_date', '>=', $to_date);
    }])->when($bed_count, function ($q, $bed_count) {
        $q->whereHas('accommodationRoomsLimited', function($query) use ($bed_count) {
            $query->where('bed_count', $bed_count);
        });
```

**Update**

```php
if ($bed_count !== null) {
    $data = Accommodation::whereHas('accommodationRoomsLimited', function($query) use ($bed_count) {
        $query->where('bed_count', $bed_count);
    })->with(['accommodationRoomsLimited.discount', 'accommodationRoomsLimited', 'accommodationRoomsLimited.roomPricingHistorySearch' => function ($query) use ($from_date, $to_date) {
        $query->whereDate('from_date', '<=', $from_date);
        $query->whereDate('to_date', '>=', $to_date);
    }])->get();
} else {
    $data = Accommodation::with([  'accommodationRoomsLimited.discount', 'accommodationRoomsLimited', 'accommodationRoomsLimited.roomPricingHistorySearch' => function ($query) use ($from_date, $to_date) {
        $query->whereDate('from_date', '<=', $from_date);
        $query->whereDate('to_date', '>=', $to_date);
    }])->get();
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: it just aplles the query on the accommodation that has the room relation but when its empty it again return the hotel

Comment: check my update. I think that if you add the wherehas first, it will solve this problem.